# Set a windows task scheduler to open excel and execute an excel macro after 5 minutes

Tags: excel, scheduled-tasks, vba

I need to run an excel macro at 3.00am in the morning. I can set up the task scheduler to be open up excel at 2.55am. However, how do i get excel to execute the macro only after 5 minutes, that it has opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nishant pointed out, you should use the `Workbook_Open` procedure to trigger a macro when the workbook opens.

The best way is to open you workbook at `3:00am` and `Workbook_Open` will trigger the macro.

Yet, if you really need to wait, you'd better use [Application OnTime](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/run-macro-on-time.htm) like this:

```
Sub RunOnTime()
    dTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
    Application.OnTime dTime, "RunMe"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could launch the excel at 3 a.m. and trigger your macro from the WORKBOOK_OPEN event by adding a

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   RunUrMacro()
End Sub
```

To your workbook.

If you absolutely need to load at 2.55 and run at 3 then you could sleep the application for 5 minutes using [Application.Wait](http://vbadud.blogspot.in/2008/03/sleep-function-in-excel-vba.html)